# Bresenhams on polygon C#

Tags: c#, bresenham

I need to pixelize / get points from closed 2d polygon. Not  outline but fill it with "pixels" voxels an retrieve their positions as points.
For now I have C# code for line rasteriation, is there any method similar for polygons?

Answer (score 0):

Just draw a polygon using your `DrawLine()`. There's no specific algorithm for drawing a polygon.

```
void DrawPoly(IEnumerable<Point> points)
{
    endpoints = points.Skip(1).Concat(new []{points.First()});
    pairs = points.Zip(endpoints, Tuple.Create);

    for(var pair in pairs)
    {
        DrawLine(pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
    }
}

void DrawLine(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    // Your Bresenham code here
}
```

---

According to the edit, you want a filled polygon. If you wish to manually implement this, try one of [these](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/polygon_filling_algorithm.htm).

It sounds like you want a big list of all the coordinates where the polygon is filled. There is likely a better way to solve the underlying problem. However, you have two options:

- Store each point as you draw it. This requires you to rewrite the algorithms mentioned above.
- Draw a polygon using an existing library. Then, take the resulting image and attach coordinates to the image matrix, flatten it into a 1D list, and then filter out the non-black values:

  ```
  /* (0,0), (0,1), ..., (w,h) */
  grid = Enumerable.Range(0, width)
      .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(0, height)
          .Select(y => new Point(x, y)));

  flattened = image.SelectMany(p => p)
      .Zip(grid, (a,b) => new {PixelValue = a, Coordinate = b});

  filledPoints = flattened.Where(p => p.PixelValue == 0)
      .Select(p => p.Coordinate);
  ```

Comment: Maybe my question was inaccurate, I am searching how to fill polygon with pixels and retrieve their positions. Like voxelization.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [polygon filling algorithm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/polygon_filling_algorithm.htm). There's a few listed there. If you want to extract a list of all the points, you can either: 1. store the point as you draw it, or 2. attach coordinates to the image matrix, flatten it into a 1D list, and then perform a `.Where(p => p.PixelValue == 0)`.

Comment: If I have simple function that draws polygon and fills it, how to attach image matrix?  See below my function

Comment: That's covered in my second bullet point. (You need to specify width, height, and image.) Since it looks like you're using a RGB image, that last line becomes `filledPoints = flattened.Where(p => p.PixelValue.Blue == 0).Select(p => p.Coordinate);`.

Comment: Wait, I have issue because I do not really want to use windows forms for this just extract info about points. Is there any way to use this function differently: // Fill polygon to screen.
    e.Graphics.FillPolygon(blueBrush, curvePoints, newFillMode);   or at how should I continue or retrieve information about screen from this line?

Answer (score 0):

How can I connect this thing with matrix to stored filled pixels?

```
public static List<Tuple<int, int>> PixelizePolygon(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    List<Tuple<int,int>> pixels = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    // Create solid brush.
    SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

    // Create points that define polygon.
    PointF point1 = new PointF(50.0F, 50.0F);
    PointF point2 = new PointF(100.0F, 25.0F);
    PointF point3 = new PointF(200.0F, 5.0F);
    PointF point4 = new PointF(250.0F, 50.0F);
    PointF point5 = new PointF(300.0F, 100.0F);
    PointF point6 = new PointF(350.0F, 200.0F);
    PointF point7 = new PointF(250.0F, 250.0F);
    PointF[] curvePoints = { point1, point2, point3, point4, point5, point6, point7 };

    // Define fill mode.
    FillMode newFillMode = FillMode.Winding;

    // Fill polygon to screen.
    e.Graphics.FillPolygon(blueBrush, curvePoints, newFillMode);



    return pixels;

}
```